# How to avoid square company logo in Odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

When I upload a new company logo in Odoo 9 it always makes generate a new image that is square - and that does **not** work on my reports. How can I force it to not generate that new square version?

Comment: You can create a new image with transparent pixels on the top and on the bottom

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the square logo by using the logo whose width is lower than 1024 px

Comment: Works also in Odoo 10.

Answer (score -1):

You can write the height that you want in the reports like this:

```xml
<template id="custom_external_layout_header" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
    <xpath expr="//img[@t-if='company.logo']" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="style">height: 50px; padding-bottom: 7px;</attribute>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

You can change the paperformat header size if you want as well.

Comment: You are not answering my question. I could maybe work around it that way in HTML but in PDF I could not get it to work. I guess its CSS support is not strong enough to do it. Forcing a square logo is in any case just really bad system design - at least without giving the option of choosing between the two formats.

Comment: I test it in Odoo 8 pdf reports and it works fine. If you define the height, the width will be proportional an the image shouldn't be a square. I assumed it would be the same in Odoo 9, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Actually I was thinking this was the CSS trick I have tried in order to hide the extra space but it probably isn't. Where do I actually put this in? In my view I have: `<t t-name="report.external_layout_header"><div class="header">...` and then normal HTML - but the above isn't normal HTML...

Comment: Just add it to a xml file in your module